# SQL: Select data based on multiple criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

Example question:

I have a table called Candy, with thousands of records, and has 10 columns with information about the candy.  I want to pull up the data for 3 records, and I have the following information:

1. Candy 1: Color = Yellow, Type = Soft, Flavor = Lemon
2. Candy 2: Color = Yellow, Type = Hard, Flavor = Lemon
3. Candy 3: Color = Red, Type = Hard, Flavor = Cherry

How do I do this?  In Psuedo-CodeEnglish, it would be:

```
Select *
From Candy
WHERE (Color = Yellow, Type = Soft, Flavor = Lemon)
AND (Candy 2: Color = Yellow, Type = Hard, Flavor = Lemon)
AND (Color = Red, Type = Hard, Flavor = Cherry);
```

But that doesn't work for me.  I'm using PL/SQL.

Comment: Did you solve this, OP?

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is that you want to find any row where any line is true, but all conditions on that line are true. That means you need something that's of the following structure: `___ OR ___ OR ___` where each `___` is itself a list of ands: `___ AND ___ AND ____`:

```
Select *
From Candy
WHERE (Color = Yellow and Type = Soft and Flavor = Lemon)
or (Color = Yellow and Type = Hard and Flavor = Lemon)
or (Color = Red and Type = Hard and Flavor = Cherry);
```

Answer (score 0):

While @Denise's answer is fine, in certain cases there is a better way to solve this type of problem using a relational database.  If you are doing a single query using a where statement is fine.  But you might have different requirements. For example, saving queries or storing candy requirements for many different users, etc.

Create a selection table.  This table has 3 columns (color, type and flavor) in the same type as your candy table.  Also add a unique identifier.  Then add the following data to the table:

```
id color   type   flavor
1  Yellow  Soft   Lemon
2  Yellow  Hard   Lemon
3  Red     Hard   Cherry
```

Now you can select your candy with the following statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM Candy C
JOIN Selection S ON C.color = S.color AND C.type=S.type AND C.flavor=S.flavor
```

Of course this can be expanded... if you want data for users add a user column to selection and then add the following to the above

```
WHERE S.User = 'Hogan'
```

to get the candies I like

Or maybe you want history.  You could add a date column to the above and then say

```
WHERE S.date = '2014-01-01'
```

to get the new year's candies.

etc.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your current query isn't working for you is because you're using `AND` instead of `OR`. There is not going to be a row in your table where `color` is both yellow and red. However, you do want to use `AND` in between each of the three conditions.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM candy
WHERE (color = 'yellow' AND type = 'soft' AND flavor = 'lemon')
    OR (color = 'yellow' AND type = 'hard' AND flavor = 'lemon')
    OR (color = 'red' AND type = 'hard' AND flavor = 'cherry');
```

Here's an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0675/1) example for you. Unfortunately, I don't know all 10 of your columns (and I don't need to) but you'll see that the query does in fact return the 3 rows expected.